# Titanium: How to check Table is exists or not in Database?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

How can I check weather specific **table** does exists or not in my **database** before execute query ?

Example : I want to check weather **Detail** table exists or not in **InfoDB**

I want to do some thing like :-

```
var createDB = Titanium.Database.open('InfoDB');
if(Detail exists in InfoDB)
  then
    var rs = createDB.execute('SELECT * FROM Detail');
```

Thanks...

Comment: db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS you can do some thing like this to create the table, not a solution but a tip

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
var createDB = Titanium.Database.open('InfoDB');

var result = createDB.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" AND name="your table name"');

if(result.isValidRow()) {
    //table found
   var rs = createDB.execute('SELECT * FROM Detail');
 }
 result.close();
```

Comment: I want to check before the execute query !

Comment: The first execute is actually fetching your table from sqlite db script `sqlite_master`.

Answer (score 2):

Solved ! I use alternate way. I use `try...catch` instead.

```
var createDB = Titanium.Database.open('InfoDB');
try
{
   var rs = createDB.execute('SELECT * FROM Detail');
}
catch(err)
{
   alert(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you like to check that before creating table

```
db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Detail (..columns..)')
```

or dropping table

```
db.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Detail')
```

avoids table exists or table not exists errors.